# ...представителя Королевы, официальн(ой/ого) главы государства

Tags: грамматика

Какого грамматического рода в данном случае "глава"?

Comment: Что такое предатавитель?

Comment: ПРЕДСТАВИТЕЛЬ, Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: …представителя Королевы, официального главы государства

При обозначении должности женщины в официальных документах и официальных сообщениях используется "мужской" вариант названия: Герой Советского союза Валентина Терешкова-Николаева.

Этот же вариант используется: в составных именных сказуемых и обособленных приложениях: Во время войны она была связистом. Материал В. Петровой, яркого публициста, опытного сотрудника газеты, вызвал большой интерес.

Comment: А мать-героиня?))) А Филипп Филиппович, который "заведующая"? А ене в официальных документах? Это диктор по TV сказал. Такое уж прямо официоз. Vera, если бы все было так просто я бы не стал вопрос задавать. Королева - она таки женщина.

Comment: А "глава" вполне может быть женского рода, вот в чем фокус.

Comment: Согласно словарю может, в текстах тоже встречается "женский род", например: Вот полный список стран, в которых английская королева является официальной главой государства.  Глава Совета Федерации посетовала, что ...".